# Strategies to interupt an asychronous function call to dump a variable

Tags: php, asynchronous, fopen, fwrite, var-dump

I have a variable that I am trying to examine its content that is called asynchronously, so I cannot do a normal var_dump($variable) for example.  I have been trying to write the variable content to a file, but not having success.  This is the function including the file write code. **I'm not sure of the data type of the $dataobject.  How can I determine its type and dump its content into the data.txt file?**

```
public function insert_record($table, $dataobject) {
  $dataobject = (array)$dataobject;

  $columns = $this->get_columns($table);
  $cleaned = array();

  $fp = fopen('../../data.txt', 'w');

   foreach ($dataobject as $field => $value) {
     //fwrite($fp, print_r($field), print_r($value) );
     // fwrite($fp, print($field), print($value) );
     // fwrite($fp, var_export($value) );
  }

fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fwrite($fp, var_export($value, true));
```

Comment: I spent a long time trying to figure out that exact line.  Thank you very much. That did exactly what I needed to do.